# How to save all files, not replacing the file?

Tags: python

I have 100 text files and I want to save it into 100 text files too. Right now, my coding can read all the files but it save only one file, which is the latest result. Here I attached the code.

```
def nama():
path = "C:/Amar/code/"
infilename = os.listdir(path)
print len(infilename)
for filename in infilename:
    print("jumpa dah" + path + "\\"+ filename)
    f = open(path + "\\" + filename, "r")  
    data = f.read()
    f.close()

    lines = data.split('\n')
    outfilename = path +  "result.txt"
    print outfilename
    f = open(outfilename , "a")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append a string that will act as a unique identifier for each output file. You can use the input filename for this:

```
outfilename = path +  filename + "_result.txt"
                     # e.g reports_result.txt
```